# React Native Webview not loading the web content

Tags: react-native

I was trying to use the WebView component in my react native application, however, the web view is not loading any url.

What I wanted to do was implement an app that has some buttons on it. And when the user clicks that button, the app should be able to open the web view with a corresponding url.

Here is my code.

(App.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Link from './Link';

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Link linkName="google" url="https://www.google.com" />
        );
    }
}
```

(Link.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text,
    WebView
} from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

'use strict'

export default class Link extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    state = {
        showWebView: false
    }

    static propTypes = {
        linkName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        url: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    renderContent = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <WebView
                source={{ uid: this.props.url }}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.state.showWebView && this.renderContent()}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ showWebView: true })} style={styles.nameButton}>
                    <Text>
                        {this.props.linkName}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    nameButton: {
        height: 50,
        width: 200,
        margin: 10,
        borderColor: '#7a42f4',
        borderWidth: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a dumb mistake.. I simply change "source={{uid: this.props.url}}" in the WebView to "source={{uri: this.props.url}}".